# Google Guava Trunk Build Problem

Tags: java, javac, guava

I am asking this question on stackoverflow as this is the suggested guava question forum indicated on the guava website (http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

I want to try out some of the unreleased new features of google guava (like the cool MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator feature). As I haven't found a google guava nightly build, I decided to try to create the jar myself. Unfortunately I am seeing the following exception from javac (on Mac OS 10.6.8) when I try to build:

```
[javac] An exception has occurred in the compiler (1.6.0_24). Please file a bug at the Java Developer Connection (http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport)  after checking the Bug Parade for duplicates. Include your program and the following diagnostic in your report.  Thank you.
[javac] java.lang.NullPointerException
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkCompatibleConcretes(Check.java:1215)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Check.checkCompatibleSupertypes(Check.java:1567)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClassBody(Attr.java:2674)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:2628)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.comp.Attr.attribClass(Attr.java:2564)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.attribute(JavaCompiler.java:1036)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile2(JavaCompiler.java:765)
[javac]     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:730)
.
.
```

I see that I am not alone in this error:

http://gump.zones.apache.org/gump/public/google-guava/google-guava/gump_work/build_google-guava_google-guava.html

I understand this looks like a Java compiler bug, but is there perhaps a workaround to get guava to compile? Or if not, is there a recent guava nightly build somewhere which I could use instead?

Comment: I can't see any error on the page you've linked to (it shows a successful build). Maybe this has been fixed? Or did you possible attach the wrong URL?

Comment: You are right. It looks like guava has been changed to work around this issue (I now just compiled successfully on my mac). Thank you for the notification.

Comment: Hi Gareth, an upvote & accept on my answer would be thanks enough :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see any error on the page you've linked to (it shows a successful build). Maybe this has been fixed? Or did you possible attach the wrong URL?

I'd try [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/).

If this is a bug in the `com.sum.*` libraries then you may find that OpenJDK does not suffer with the same problem.